# How does Go convert a 3-byte sequence into the appropriate Unicode char?

Tags: go, encoding, utf-8, byte

If we have the chars, 世界, they correspond to the bytes 228 184 150 231 149 140, 3 bytes each. If I simply have `[]byte{228, 184, 150, 231, 149, 140}`, how does Go know to group them into 3 bytes each?
If I try to print out `fmt.Println(string([]byte{228}))`, I get a mystery ? symbol. Is it when Go compiler sees 228 and knows that it needs to read more bytes to find the right char?

Comment: This is how UTF8 works and is unrelated to Go.

Comment: I found out it's better to just convert to []rune if you know the string will have non-ASCII chars

Answer (score 1):

The first byte of a code point specifies the total number of bytes in the code point. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for details. The Go language and libraries use this count to convert a sequence of bytes into code points (also known as runes)

The terminal receives an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence when 228 is written without the two trailing bytes. Your terminal displays invalid bytes as the replacement character �.

See the [Go Blog Strings article](https://blog.golang.org/strings) for more details about strings, bytes  and runes in the Go language.

Comment: I did read the article before asking the question; I just didn't understand how 228 signals that there are 3 bytes in the sequence. I also found out in another blog post that it is best to just convert string to []rune if you know the chars will not only be ASCII.

Comment: @100BugsOntheWall  Conversion to []rune is sometimes the right thing, but It's often convenient to work with UTF-8 directly using `for range` and the unicode/utf8 package.